# How to return distance and score in spatial search using spring-data-solr

Tags: java, spring-mvc, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I'm writing a Spring MVC based Search API using spring-data-solr 1.0.0.RELEASE with Solr 4.4.0 and Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE.

I'm able to run basic queries but unable to find any good example how can I return score and distance:geodist() in the results.

I know I can get results from Solr using query like

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/events/select?q=*:*&spatial=true&pt=51.435872%2C-0.427529&sfield=position&d=20&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=-1&facet.field=categoryIds&fl=score,*,distance:geodist()&sort=geodist()+asc
```

but I don't know how to get score and distance properties returned from Solr using spring-data-solr. I have tried following code

```
FacetQuery search = new SimpleFacetQuery();

Criteria conditions;// = new Criteria();
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchCriteria.getSearchString()))
        conditions = new Criteria(EventDocument.FIELD_EVENT).contains(searchCriteria.getSearchString());

if(searchCriteria.isLocationKnown()){
        conditions.and(new Criteria(EventDocument.FIELD_POSITION).within(new GeoLocation(searchCriteria.getLatitude(), searchCriteria.getLongitude()), new Distance(searchCriteria.getDistance(), Distance.Unit.MILES)));
        conditions.and(new Criteria(CommonParams.FL).is("score,distance:geodist(),*"));
    } else{
        conditions.and(new Criteria(CommonParams.FL).is("score,*"));
    }

search.addCriteria(conditions);
FacetPage page = solrTemplate.queryForFacetPage(search, EventDocument.class);
```

but getting following Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: undefined field fl; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: undefined field fl
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: undefined field fl; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: undefined field fl
org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:122)
org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.executeSolrQuery(SolrTemplate.java:330)
org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.query(SolrTemplate.java:326)
org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.queryForFacetPage(SolrTemplate.java:285)
com.johnstonpress.api.repository.EventDocumentRepositoryImpl.search(EventDocumentRepositoryImpl.java:72)
com.johnstonpress.api.service.SearchEventServiceImpl.search(SearchEventServiceImpl.java:106)
com.johnstonpress.api.controller.EventsSearchController.searchEvents(EventsSearchController.java:124)
com.johnstonpress.api.controller.EventsSearchController.search(EventsSearchController.java:68)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**Thanks for any attention and help!!!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set `fl` you have to use `query.addProjectionOnField(String fieldname)`.

```
    SimpleQuery query = new SimpleQuery(conditions);
    query.addProjectionOnField("*");
    query.addProjectionOnField("score");
```

For mapping `score` into `EventDocument` you'll have to add the property as follows.

```
    @Indexed(value = "score", readonly = true)
    private Float score;
```

Unfortunately there seems to be an issue with `geodist()` that might be caused by the way spring data solr creates spatial query.
Opended [DATASOLR-130](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATASOLR-130) for that.

---

Distance can be requested using `SolrCallback` along with `SolrTemplate` by setting spatial paramters yourself.

```
    SimpleQuery query = new SimpleQuery(conditions);
    query.addProjectionOnField("*");
    query.addProjectionOnField("distance:geodist()");

    DefaultQueryParser qp = new DefaultQueryParser();
    final SolrQuery solrQuery = qp.constructSolrQuery(query);
    solrQuery.add("sfield", "store");
    solrQuery.add("pt", GeoConverters.GeoLocationToStringConverter.INSTANCE.convert(new GeoLocation(45.15, -93.85)));
    solrQuery.add("d", GeoConverters.DistanceToStringConverter.INSTANCE.convert(new Distance(5)));

    List<EventDocument> result = template.execute(new SolrCallback<List<EventDocument>>() {

      @Override
      public List<EventDocument> doInSolr(SolrServer solrServer) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
        return template.getConverter().read(solrServer.query(solrQuery).getResults(), EventDocument.class);
      }
    });
```

A litte bit easier would be to provide required parameters for `geodist()`.

```
    SimpleQuery query = new SimpleQuery(conditions);
    query.addProjectionOnField("*");
    query.addProjectionOnField("distance:geodist(store," + GeoConverters.GeoLocationToStringConverter.INSTANCE.convert(new GeoLocation(45.15, -93.85)) + ")");
    Page<EventDocument> result = template.queryForPage(query, EventDocument.class);
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Christoph-Strbl for the quick one, I'll give it a try and will respond. In the mean time, can you think of any alternate for geodist()? Otherwise I'll have to switch from spring-data-solr to Solrj as an alternate option. Any pointer will help.

Comment: Hi @Christoph-Strobl I have tried your suggestion and I yes addProjectionOnField is working fine except for the geodist(). Sorting by distance is crucial for my application. Is there any alternate option available for sorting by distance or you  thing I can't this API until this  issue is resolved?

PS: IF this is not the best place for asking questions about spring data solr, can you please point me to any forum where I may ask few more related/similar questions?

Comment: Hi @aamir-yaseen,
stckoverflow is a fine place to ask, you can also try the [spring.io forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data).
I just edited my answer above and hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christoph-Strbl, Very useful information and solves my problem.
    query.addProjectionOnField("distance:geodist(store," + GeoConverters.GeoLocationToStringConverter.INSTANCE.convert(new GeoLocation(45.15, -93.85)) + ")");
    solved my problem :)