# How to sort by geodist() function in Spring Solr Data?

Tags: solr, spring-data, spatial, spatial-query, solr6

Ciao,
I'm unable to get the following solr query working with Spring Solr Data.

**q=name:*rsa*&sfield=coordinates&pt=-8.506854,115.262478&sort=geodist()%20asc**

The query works if I put it inside solr admin console, but it doesn't work with spring solr data. I didn't find examples about geodist sorting inside documentation so I created a CustomRepository with the following function:

```
public Page<StructureDocument> findStructuresByNameAndCoordinates(String value, Point point, Pageable page) {

StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
queryBuilder.append("name:*").append(value).append("*");
queryBuilder.append("&sfield=coordinates");
queryBuilder.append("&pt=").append(point.getX()).append(",").append(point.getY());
queryBuilder.append("&sort=geodist() asc");

Query query = new SimpleQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria(queryBuilder.toString())).setPageRequest(page);
```

But it doesn't work because of syntax error (seems that Solrj doesn't like this chars (). This is the error:

```
; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'name:*francesco*&sfield=coordinates&pt=-8.506854,115.262478&sort=geodist() asc': Encountered " ")" ") "" at line 1, column 71.
```

How can I sort by geodist function with spring solr data??

Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried to use also **ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars()**, syntax error disappear but solr returns strange results..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here [SOLR Spring Data geospatial query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461757/solr-spring-data-geospatial-query)

```
@Override
public Page<StructureDocument> 
findStructuresByNameAndCoordinates(String value, Point point, Pageable 
page){
SimpleQuery query = new SimpleQuery().setPageRequest(page);
query.addProjectionOnField("*");
query.addProjectionOnField("score");

StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
buf.append("{!geofilt pt=");
buf.append(point.getX());
buf.append(",");
buf.append(point.getY());
buf.append(" sfield=coordinates d=");
buf.append(2000.0);
buf.append(" score=distance}");

query.addCriteria(new SimpleStringCriteria(buf.toString()));

FilterQuery searchTerm = new SimpleFilterQuery();
searchTerm.addCriteria(new Criteria("name").contains(value));
query.addFilterQuery(searchTerm);

query.addSort(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "score"));
```

Moreover I added to my solr document "score" attribute, used to store distance value calculated by geodist function.

```
@Score
private Double score;
```

This solution works, but I know there's a better way that actually for me doesn't work, see this link. I'll continue to investigate it.

[How to return distance and score in spatial search using spring-data-solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332197/how-to-return-distance-and-score-in-spatial-search-using-spring-data-solr?rq=1)